# How do I find a vector perpendicular to two given vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

$(2, -1, 1)$, $(3, 1, 1)$

Suppose the normal $N = (a, b, c)$. Then we have a system of equations:

$2a – b + c = 0$

$3a + b + c = 0$

where $a$ = $ \frac {-2c}5$ and $b = \frac c5$.

I am not sure if any of that is correct. Supposing it is and letting $c$ be anything I get $N = (-4, 5, 10)$ which is not perpendicular to either vector.

Please, explain how to deal with the equation above to get correct $N$.

Comment: Also, is this homework?

Comment: Yes, sort of. I am just going through exercises from a Linear Algebra book.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, in this situation I just take the cross product of the two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is correct, though the calculation is wrong. For $c=10$, the vector is actually (-4,2,10), which is perpendicular.

The meaning is that you found a  family of vectors which are all collinear and normal to the plane containing the first 2 vectors